# How do I change what tomcat ${appserver.lib} points to?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ant

I'm doing the tutorial on http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html and when I try to build the ant build I'm getting the error:

```
D:\workspace\springapp\build.xml:85: D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.14\lib does not exist.
```

The problem seems to be because **"${appserver.lib}"** is pointing at **D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.14\lib** whereas the correct directory should be **C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\lib** - notice the different version of tomcat directory name. How do I change what this is pointing to? I've already set %CATALINA_HOME% as the correct path and added %CATALINA_HOME%\bin to path

I'm using Windows 7 64bit with Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply changing

> appserver.home=C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.35

which is correct directory in `build.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed it!